# Как в PyQt запустить модуль.py с помощью QProcess?

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qprocess

Как в *PyQt5* запустить файл с помощью `QProcess`?

При нажатии на кнопку ничего не происходит.

---

**test_QProsess.py**

```
import sys
import subprocess

from PyQt5 import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtCore import QProcess

class StartProcess(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(StartProcess, self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(50, 50, 500, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle('Главное окно')
        self.sprocess()

    def sprocess(self):
        btn_run = QPushButton('Пуск', self)
        filepath = "hello.py"
        btn_run.clicked.connect(lambda checked, arg=filepath: self.execute(arg))

        self.show()

    def execute(self, filepath):
        QProcess.startDetached(filepath)

if not QApplication.instance():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
else:
    app = QApplication.instance()

GUI = StartProcess()
app.exec_()
```

---

***hello.py***

```
print('Привет!')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import sys
# ??? import subprocess
# ??? from PyQt5 import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtCore import QProcess


class StartProcess(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(StartProcess, self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(50, 50, 500, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle('Главное окно')
        self.sprocess()

    def sprocess(self):
        btn_run = QPushButton('Пуск', self)
        filepath = "hello.py"
        btn_run.clicked.connect(lambda checked, arg=filepath: self.execute(arg))

    def execute(self, filepath):
#        QProcess.startDetached(filepath)
        QProcess.startDetached(f"python {filepath}")                 # !!!


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = StartProcess()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]